# Flutter and android studio error: Google Play Store is missing

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am getting this error while doing google Authentication using firebase. When I run my app, Buffering comes while clicking on google button.

```
name: google_signin_example
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  # google sign in
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  # state management
  provider: 5.0.0

  # icon of google
  font_awesome_flutter: 9.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

this is the pub spec.yaml file.

Error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52271/JcyHJ3SiTHE=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for arm64...
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2685): Google Play Store is missing.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2685): Google Play Store is missing.
W/DynamiteModule( 2685): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.auth.api.fallback not found.
E/flutter ( 2685): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(213)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)
E/flutter ( 2685): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter ( 2685): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter ( 2685): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2685): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:356:43)
E/flutter ( 2685): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2685): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:235:30)
E/flutter ( 2685): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2685): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
E/flutter ( 2685): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2685):
```

Answer (score 18):

I solved this error by creating a new virtual device that implements the Google Play Store services (It is needed for Google Login).

1. Open Android Studio > **AVD Manager** > **Create Virtual Device**
2. Choose a device that implements the Play Store, like shown in the following image:
   [Screenshoot of Virtual device with Google Play Services included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCfMM.png)

If it doesn't work, you could try to test the feature using a Virtual Device using the "API 29" (Android 10).

Hope it was helpful!